# Google Closure Compiler SourceMap with multiple files

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler, bundling-and-minification, source-maps

How can I instruct google closure compiler to create a map file for my minified files that are in different folders preserving the right relative paths.

I cannot even specify a sourceRoot as option in sourcemap generation

I have a javascript file in `/Js/common.js` and then some other files in `/Admin/js/plugin.js`

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar "..\SolutionItems\Javascript\compiler.jar" --js ".\Js\Common.js" --js ".\Admin\assets\js\plugins.js" %*  --source_map_format=V3 --js_output_file "./Admin/Asset/Js/admin.min.js" --create_source_map "./Admin/Asset/Js/admin.min.map"
```

this is the generated .map file

```
{
"version":3,
"file":"./Admin/Asset/Js/admin.min.js",
...
"sources":[".\\Js\\Common.js",".\\Admin\\assets\\js\\plugins.js"],
..
}
```

but it is misinterpreted by the browser because it use relative path from `/Admin/Asset/Js/`
and it try to find those js in `/Admin/Asset/Js/js/common.js` and `/Admin/Asset/Js//Admin/Asset/js/common.js`

-----UPDATE-----

For future reference:
if you don't want to copy the closure compiler to the js folder (like me) it is enought to change the current folder before calling it.

```
cd c:\Website\Admin\Asset\js
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\SolutionItems\Javascript\compiler.jar"--js "../../../Js/Common.js" --js "plugins.js"  --source_map_format=V3 --js_output_file "admin.min.js" --create_source_map "admin.min.map"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the compiler from the `admin/assets/js/` folder. You can specify output paths for the other resources.